# How can I recieve notifications from a database to run a service?

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, notifications

Just a quick question and it may seem simple to some, yet I have not figured out a way yet... So for one of my classes, I am creating a website which runs an errand service. It has a simple form which retrieves information that the user would need help with (i.e. get plastic cups and bring them to me). So far I have my form hooked up to Google's free FireBase and that serves as my database to store any information that is submitted through my HTML form. Now, I was wondering if there is any way for me to receive some sort of a notification (through text, or anything) anytime someone submitted a request.

I am willing to use a different service which allows such a feature. To sum up, I need help finding some sort of a feature or an add-on that can send me a direct notification any time a user fills out a request form, any time of the day. It is inconvenient for me to refresh my Firebase every other minute to see if any new information appears, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance, and ask any questions if need.

Comment: There are various email and sms services you could use or make secondary request to a server you control to send messages from

Answer (score 0):

What about adding another page to your site that constantly checks (javascript `setTimeout`) for the database state and show the results? You won't need to refresh, just keep the page open.